# Create an array from an array based on value and include matches within as an array

Tags: php

I'm wanting to group my data by a specific value (parent name) and then merge all the items that share the same parent name under a "items" array

However it's overwriting the items array, not adding to it, so for example "items" in the output should have multiple items not just one.

Any ideas?

```
$result = array();
foreach ($page->products_codes as $option) {
    $result[$option->parent->name]["title"] = $option->parent->title;
    $result[$option->parent->name]["items"] = $option->title;
}
```

Outputs as:

```
array (
  'fixture' => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Fixture',
    'items' => 'Pinhole90 Fixed with LED51',
  ),
  'finish' => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Finish',
    'items' => 'RAL',
  ),
  'ip-rating' => 
  array (
    'title' => 'IP Rating',
    'items' => 'IP54',
  ),
  'emergency' => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Emergency',
    'items' => 'Maintained 3hr Self Test',
  ),
  'installation' => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Installation',
    'items' => 'Plaster-kit for seamless flush appearance',
  ),
  'led' => 
  array (
    'title' => 'LED',
    'items' => 'LED50 ONE',
  ),
  'cct' => 
  array (
    'title' => 'CCT',
    'items' => '90 CRI 4000K',
  ),
  'beam-angle' => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Beam Angle',
    'items' => '38°',
  ),
  'protocol' => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Protocol',
    'items' => 'Bluetooth',
  ),
  'louvre-lens' => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Louvre/Lens',
    'items' => 'Heavy Spread Lens',
  ),
)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: As per [ask], don't upload pictures of code / data - such data is text, and should be provided as text, for ease of use. If you provide your source data in the form of a `var_export()` output, we can much more easily work with it to test code, provide demos and examples etc. Please also provide an example of the expected output based on the code you're trying to write. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the preferred data structure you specified:

```php
$result = array();
foreach ($page->products_codes as $option) {
    $result[$option->parent->name]["title"] = $option->parent->title;
    $result[$option->parent->name]["items"][] = $option;
}

$result = array_values($result);
```

Here's a working example: https://3v4l.org/u9XBk

Comment: Thanks for the help. This only seems to return one item in the items array whereas it should be adding any option that has the same key. For example in my screenshot you can see 'finish' for example has multiple arrays (options) and these should all be merged into one 'items' array if that makes sense?

Comment: `$result[$option->parent->name]["items"][] = $option` must be overwriting the items array whereas it needs to add to it

Comment: If you look at the output in the link in my answer you should see the items array can contain multiple items. The line you mentioned will be pushing to the items array, not overwriting it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php